# The two sides of my double pole thermostat aren't turning on at the same time

Tags: heater, baseboard

I have three baseboard heaters connected to a single double-pole thermostat. Two heaters are in series and connected to one 240v pole, the other is a single heater with its own 240v pole. The problem is, the single heater side trips at a much higher temp, so I end up not using it. FWIW, the setup worked just fine until I decided to switch out the old thermostat for a new one.

Is there a way to sync up both poles so they trip at the same temp?

Comment: A lot of this doesn't add up. Not clear how much is technical problems vs. terminology confusion. Are the heaters 240V or 120V heaters? Can you upload pictures of the wiring at the thermostat and any other relevant junction boxes?

Comment: Use a single pole thermostat controlling a DPST relay.

Comment: A double pole thermostat switches two switches at the same time at a set temperature.  There are different ways to wire it up, and the one you describe is not a typical one, it serves no purpose and I think you may be describing it incorrectly.  What I do not understand is "trips at a much higher temp".   What does that mean?  You have one thermostat.

Answer (score 3):

The normal application of a double-pole thermostat to 240V heaters is that all the heaters are in parallel, connected to both poles, and both poles of power are connected to the thermostat, so none of the heaters turn on until both poles do, at which point they all do.

The wiring you are describing sounds exceedingly suspect. Are you trying to run two different circuits from one thermostat?